# dataTables search bar returns incorrect results

Tags: datatables

When using the searchbar to search for a product, I also get results that do not contain the string I input.

For example, inputting "70" shows the following results : HeatMaster 120, HeatMaster 70, HeatMaster 85.

This is because the rows containing this data have another column, numerical, which also contains "70" (e.g: 170); is there a way I can force this plugin to consider only one specified column when searching ? Or a plugin for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Doing a little test-driven research, I found out that the default behavior of the search box is to search **all** the fields and return all the rows that contain the input string; to search on only a specific column, I used the columnFilter add-on for jQuery dataTables.

http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html